# В какой БД хранить большое количество текстовых данных, доступ к которым нужен быстрый, но не часто?

Tags: база-данных

Работа ведется с текстовыми данными, куски текста от 1 Кб до нескольких Мб, средняя длинна сейчас 16 Кб.

При каждом изменении необходимо сохранять предыдущий вариант текста для истории версий. Обращение к истории версий будет не частым, но все же хотелось бы чтобы быстрым.

Соответственно, хранимые данные имеют формат { id | text }

В каком виде лучше хранить эту историю, в какой БД? По планам история очень быстро разрастется до десятков и сотен Гб, а ее необходимо периодически бекапить (в идеале ежедневно).

Comment: > ... разрастется до десятков и сотен Гб ... ... бекапить (в идеале ежедневно) ...

@Антон Смуров, я могу ошибаться, но на мой взгляд, тут надо больше задуматься о конфигурации железа сервера. Кстати, не в последнюю очередь о дисковом простране... Пусть не сотня, но бэкапить десяток гектар в день - серьезное число нарастет за годик.

Comment: Никто не говорит о хранении всех ежедневных бекапов. Вполне достаточно стандартной схемы 6/3/3.
Задача - иметь максимально свежий бекап на случай падения сервера, посыпавшегося диска, нападения злоумышленников, неудачного апдейта сервиса...

Comment: @Антон Смуров, на самом деле, я не делал акцент на винте. Для быстрой обработки, как вы понимаете, важна оперативка, проц, возможно *RAID 10*. Опять же повторюсь, что я могу ошибаться, но при мощной конфигурации сервера, даже MySQL с этой задачей нормально справиться. Но по таким вопросам, думаю, что боле правильно ответят на [РутКоде][1]

   [1]:http://admin.hashcode.ru/

Comment: @Deonis основной сервис работает на собственном физическом сервере не самой слабой комплектации и данные хранятся как раз в MySQL, но в отношении обсуждаемой задачи я волнуюсь за бекапы. Дампить табличку весом в 10-100 Гб будет весьма затруднительно. Конечно, можно бекапить файлы БД, но там ведь тоже есть подводные камни.

Comment: @Антон Смуров, учтите, что в простых случаях (без ухищрений) на время бэкапа базу надо останавливать.

Для сотен гигабайт, даже при весьма приличной скорости бэкапа 20 Мбайт/сек это займет пару часов. 

Советую заранее тщательно продумать схему работы вашей системы и состав железа (может на нем такая задача вообще не решается?).